# Angularjs, Rails 4 and Paperclip how to get thumbnail image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, paperclip, thumbnails

I'm recently trying to switch my Rails server app to Angularjs. When everything works fine and I can get my json data from the server, I actually don't know how to get image from Paperclip. Using only Rails, I used to do it that way :

```
model.logo.url(:small)
```

which works fine. However, how to do that using Angularjs? The only json object I'm getting looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Item1",
    "logo":"/system/items/logos/000/000/002/original/wallpaper_1.jpg?1382574502",
    "logo_file_name":"wallpaper_1.jpg",
    "logo_content_type":"image/jpeg",
    "logo_file_size":578032,
    "logo_updated_at":"2013-10-24T00:28:22.000Z"
  }
]
```

If I print `logo`, it loads the full image (1920x1200) which is not ideal as it's heavy to load and also since I put a `circle` css effect, the image does not really scale and it looks pretty ugly. How to get the `:small` thumbnail?

Thanks a lot

**Edit**
Thanks @Muntasim, it works now :

```
def as_json(options={})
  { name: self.name, email: self.email, phone: self.phone, mobile: self.mobile, slug: self.slug, logo: self.logo.url(:small) }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the default json form of the object. Here you need to customize that like:

```
object.as_json(id: id, name: name, small_logo_url: logo.url(:small))
```

That should give you:

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"Item1",
"small_logo_url":"your expected file url..",
}
```

If you have collection of objects then you will get an array of json object

Comment: But how do you do that when you fetch all the pictures in the database? Like Medium.all

Comment: please look at the edit section of the question. if you override `as_json` in the model and render json from Model.all it should work